# How to add value at click on toggle switch?

Tags: jquery, html, css, laravel

For the moment, I have an Offer field with on request / on offer values. I need to add value on it `value="1"` and `value="0"` at click..How can I be able to do that?Thank you.

**Here is my view for current field**

```
<div class="col col-3" style="width: 23% !important;right: 8px;position: relative;padding-right: 7px;padding-left: 0px;">
                                    <label class="label">Offer</label>
                                    <label class="select">

                                    {{ Form::select('on_offer', [
                                           '' => 'Select ',
                                           '1' => 'On Offer',
                                           '0' => 'On Request'],null,['id'=>'header_on_offer']
                                        ) }}
                                        <i></i>
                                    </label>
                                </div>
```

**My new toggle button**

```
<label class="toggle">
    <input type="checkbox" value="0">
    <i class="no-rounded privancy"></i>
</label>
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/mburnette/pen/LxNxNg

Comment: i need to add value on it. `value="1"` and `value="0"` at click.

Comment: That is not what you have asked in question, is it? Edit the question and explain what you need exactly so people can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a checkbox only sends it's value/name when it's checked. so to do as you want, you need something else to send the information when its not checked.
there is a simple trick for that

```
<label class="toggle">
    <input name="on_offer" value="1" type="hidden" />
    <input name="on_offer" value="0" type="checkbox">
    <i class="no-rounded privancy"></i>
</label>
```

If the checkbox is not checked, the value will be sent from the hidden input. When it is checked, it will override the variable sent to 0 since they have `The same name attribute` (and it's not an array)